# Azure Pipeline refuses to deploy from zip instead calling from blob which doesn't exist

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Very much still new to YAML, but i've showed this to a colleague who's equally confused as me. I've built a CI/CD pipeline, and the CI end seems to work just fine. The pipeline claims its deploying a function app successfully, but when I go to check, there's nothing in the function app, and the output code from the pipeline seems to be calling from a blob storage folder that doesn't exist. We can't work out how to change the behaviour of it.

Is this something anyone has seen before?

This is the YAML:

```
# Python Function App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Python function app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux function app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'ab1c86d0-0d0c-4029-913b-e5483df967b2'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'categoriserfunctionapp'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: ''

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.6 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today
        architecture: 'x64'

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'test'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN (f1f3e234-557b-4acd-b353-2ff89c547e49)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: 'categoriserfunctionapp'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.9'
```

And this is the output from the CD end:

```
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6330661Z ##[section]Starting: AzureFunctionApp
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6442433Z ==============================================================================
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6442718Z Task         : Azure Functions
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6443009Z Description  : Update a function app with .NET, Python, JavaScript, PowerShell, Java based web applications
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6443282Z Version      : 1.208.2
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6443454Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6443686Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurefunctiontroubleshooting
2022-09-27T15:59:26.6443957Z ==============================================================================
2022-09-27T15:59:27.4092341Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'categoriserfunctionapp'
2022-09-27T15:59:30.9793711Z Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"https://categoriserfunc9c44.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1664294369833.zip?***"}
2022-09-27T15:59:32.4412565Z Updated App Service Application settings.
2022-09-27T15:59:32.4414182Z Updated WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Application setting to https://categoriserfunc9c44.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1664294369833.zip?***
2022-09-27T15:59:37.4527980Z Syncing triggers for function app
2022-09-27T15:59:39.3782043Z Sync triggers for function app completed successfully
2022-09-27T15:59:41.0691225Z Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : categoriserfunctionapp
2022-09-27T15:59:41.3968439Z App Service Application URL: https://categoriserfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net
2022-09-27T15:59:41.4063927Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureFunctionApp
```

We tried changing the hardcode of WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE but it seems to have changed itself back since I refreshed the function app.

Does anyone have any ideas for fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can successfully deploy to azure function app with a slight modification based on the YAML you provided.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '<ARM Service Connection Name>'
  resourceGroupName: '<Resource Group Name of storage>'
  # Function app name
  functionAppName: '<Your Function App Name>'
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: ''

  storage_str: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.9 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today
        architecture: 'x64'

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'test'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/'
          - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appName: '$(functionAppName)'
              resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
              appSettings: |
                [
                  {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "$(storage_str)",
                    "slotSetting": false
                  }
                ]
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: '$(functionAppName)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.9'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

From your description, the blob file doesn't exist? If so, the function will not execute successfully.

You must make sure there is a file to use for 'run from package'.

There are several problems with your YAML which may cause the issue:

1. Variables in YAML are not fully used. The service connection and variable definitions in the Deployment stage are different (I have changed to the same).
2. The python version used is different from the azure function app version (I have changed to the same).

By the way, In order to rule out the problem that the storage is controlled by some policy or program, you can create a new storage to test and provide the connection string in the above YAML file (the location of the package your function app is based on is determined by AzureWebJobsStorage, the above YAML can be Change settings before actual deployment.).

And additional, if you can deploy the function app with no problem on local(such as VS Code), then you can use something like below to deploy the function app.

```
trigger:
- none
variables:
- name: System.debug
  value: true
pool:
  VMAS #agent based on your local machine.
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'func azure functionapp publish xxx --build remote'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

My repo structure likes below:

[image]

Comment: your answers are awesome! Could you please take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858965/azure-devops-install-package-cmdlet

Comment: In the end with your suggestions we narrowed down the remaining problem to one of file structure, the init needed to be in with the function as well as all the above changes. Thank you!